# What happens when I call a function in a DLL

Tags: c#, c++, memory

I use a dll compiled from C++ code (LPSolve, see http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/), from my C# code. I use the API to build a linear programming model, and subsequently solve it. I call functions such as:

```
[DllImport("lpsolve55.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool add_columnex
           (int lp, int count, double[] column, int[] rowno);
```

I am wondering what happens, memorywise, when I call such a function and the ints and arrays that I created in managed code leave scope (in the c# code). Will they be eligible for garbage collection? What does this mean for the c++ code? Or are the ineligible, and in that case: why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function prototype is using plain old datatypes and arrays, the memory for these values is pinned in place and then the native code acts directly on the data. Then when the function returns, the memory is unpinned and can be garbage collected.

In other words, they never leave the scope.

In terms of the C++ code, if it needs to store any of the data then it will need to take a copy of the data passed into it and then manage that memory itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think Nick has covered the basic part, this is just to add more information. Array of int/double are considered as blittable types (types that have same layout in managed/unmanaged worlds) - these are typically get pinned when Marshalled. So you don't have to about GC. Also, what you have done indicates passing array by value - in such case, marshaller treats this as In parameter - in case, your unmanaged dll is going to update values in array then I would suggest you to mark it as In/Out parameter (e.g. `[In, Out]double[] column`). For more info:

1. Blittable and Non-Blittable Types:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx
2. Copying and Pinning: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23acw07k.aspx
3. Marshalling Arrays: http://learning.infocollections.com/ebook%202/Computer/Programming/General/Programming.With.Microsoft.Dot.NET/LiB0948.htm

Answer (score 1):

If your app doesn't crash with an AccessViolationException after using it for a while (past a garbage collection) then it is pretty safe to assume that the unmanaged code made a copy of the array elements you passed it.  This is the normal thing to do, the library would otherwise be very hard to use from native code as well.  There also ought to be an API function that lets you clear or re-initialize the model, that one should be releasing the memory.

Answer (score 0):

The C or C++ function has a prototype like this:

```
 bool add_columnex(int lp, int count, double[] column, int[] rowno);
```

The parameters lp and count are passed by value. The parameters column and rowno are also passed by value but the actual data is passed by reference, the function `add_columnex` will have to dereference column and rowno. This dereferentiation is only allowed during the function call. When the function returns, these parameters are out of scope. The kind of derenferentation must be in the contract of the interface.

When the function returns all arguments get out of scope and there is no mean that the function could do anything after call. If the function stores copies of the arguments, i.e. the address of the double or rowno array, this must be allowed by the contract. In that case you would get in trouble. A better contract would be that the function must copy the dereferenced data.